# drop everything to the right of a hyphen in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using Oracle SQL developer 2012. My data looks like `'valueA-valueB'`. I want to strip the content after `-` and populate with rest.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of [`substr`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions162.htm) and [`instr`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions068.htm):

```
SELECT SUBSTR(my_column, 1, INSTR(my_column, '-') - 1)
FROM   my_table
```